# Codeforces question on Binary Lifting and LCA

Tags: c++, algorithm

Recently, I was solving [this](https://codeforces.com/gym/102694/problem/C) problem on Codeforces, but I failed the testcases. I can't see the testcases, nor can I see other's solutions because it is a gym question.  Since, I cannot view the testcases where my code is failing, I need some help. I promise that the code is quite readable. Question is mainly on Binary lifting and LCA calculation.

> As probably know, sloths live on trees. Accordingly, David has a pet sloth which he lets play on his unweighted trees when he solves programming problems. Occasionally, David will notice that his sloth is located on a particular node  in the tree, and ask it to move to some other node .
>
> Of course, the sloth is as well-intentioned as can be, but alas, it only has enough energy to move across at most  edges. If the sloth needs to cross fewer than  edges to get to node , it will get there and then take a nap. Otherwise, it will get as close as possible before it retires and hangs idly awaiting further digestion.
>
> Where will the sloth end up? Also, since this happens quite often, David would like you to answer  queries, each one of the similar form.
>
> Input
>
> The first line will contain a single integer , the number of nodes in the tree. The following −1 lines will contain two integers  and , describing the edges in the tree. These edges will form a tree.
>
> After that, there will be a single line containing an integer , the number of times David will motivate his sloth to move.  lines follow, each containing three integers , , and : the node the sloth starts on, the node David asks the sloth to move to, and the energy the sloth has when starting.

```
int LOGN = 19;
int n;
int timer = 0;
vector<int> adj[300005];
bool vis[300005];
int p[300005], tin[300005], tout[300005];
vector<int> d(300005,0);
int dp[300005][20];

void dfs(int v, int parent)
{
    tin[v] = ++timer;
    if (parent != -1)
        d[v] = d[parent] + 1;
    p[v] = parent;
    dp[v][0] = parent;
    for (int i = 1; i < LOGN; i++){
        if (dp[v][i &mdash; 1] == -1)
            dp[v][i] = -1;
        else
            dp[v][i] = dp[dp[v][i &mdash; 1]][i &mdash; 1];
    }
    for (auto u : adj[v]){
        if (u != parent)
            dfs(u, v);
    }
    tout[v] = ++timer;
}
bool isAncestor(int p, int c){ // check if p is ancestor of c
    return (tin[p] <= tin[c] && tout[p] >= tout[c]);
}
int lift(int v, int steps) //find the y-th ancestor of x
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i){
        if ((1 << i) & steps){
            v = dp[v][i];
            if (v == -1)
                return -1;
            steps -= (1 << i);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
int LCA(int u, int v)
{
    if (isAncestor(u, v))
        return u;
    if (isAncestor(v, u))
        return v;
    for (int i = 18; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (dp[u][i] == -1)// -1 should not be passed
            continue;
        if (!isAncestor(dp[u][i], v))
            u = dp[u][i];
    }
    return dp[u][0];
}
void solve()
{
    cin>>n;
    timer=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){// Input
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        x--;y--;
        adj[x].pb(y);
        adj[y].pb(x);
    }
    dfs(0,-1);
    tout[0]=++timer;
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    for(int z=0;z<q;z++){
        int u,v,energy;
        cin>>u>>v>>energy;
        u--;v--;
        if(isAncestor(u,v))// u is ancestor of v
        {
            if(d[v]-d[u]<=energy)// reachable
                cout<<v+1<<endl;
            else{// midway: lift
                int res=lift(v,energy);
                cout<<res+1<<endl;
            }           
        }
        else if(isAncestor(v,u))// v is ancestor of u
        {
            if(d[u]-d[v]<=energy)// reachable
                cout<<v+1<<endl;
            else{/// midway: lift
                int res=lift(u,d[u]-d[v]-energy);
                cout<<res+1<<endl;
            }       
        }
        else{
            int lca=LCA(u,v);
            int dist=d[u]+d[v]-2*d[lca];
            if(energy>=dist)
                cout<<v+1<<endl;
            else{   
                // find vertex of the path from u to v with distance of energy from u
                int dist1=d[u]-d[lca];
                int dist2=d[v]-d[lca];
                // lies on the path from u to LCA
                if(energy<=dist1){
                    int res=lift(u,energy)+1;
                    cout<<res<<endl;
                }
                // lies on the path from LCA to v
                else{
                    int rem=energy-dist1;
                    dist2-=rem;
                    int res=lift(v,dist2)+1;
                    cout<<res<<endl;
                }   
            }
        }           
    }
}
signed main() 
{ 
    FAST;
    solve();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *I need some help* -- You wrote all of this code, and you decided to spend time on a site that doesn't tell you what fails.  Thus you must have had some idea of how to debug your own code if it comes to the point where you are told your code fails.

Comment: OT:  prefer to use a container of struct rather than parallel arrays.  At least, make 300005 a named constant, so you only have make one change to modify the capacities of the arrays.

Comment: In your `main`, what is `FAST;`?